# If for every $z\in G$ there is $n$ such that $f^{(n)}(z)=0$, then $f$ is a polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

> > Let $G$ be an open and connected set of the complex plane 
> >     $\mathbb{C}$ and $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be analytic, such that for each 
> >     $z\in G$ there is $n=n(z)\in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
> >     $f^{(n)}(z)=0$. Prove that $f$ is a polynomial.

**Attempt** It seemed to me like a Baire-type application, since $\displaystyle G=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{z\in G:~f^{(n)}(z)=0\}$, but there is no completeness on $G$ to work it that way.

**Edit**. Motivated by [Entire function with vanishing derivatives?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995105/entire-function-with-vanishing-derivatives), let 
$n:G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}:~n(z)=\min\{k:~f^{(k)}(z)=0\}$ which is well defined and $\displaystyle G=\displaystyle \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}n^{-1}(\{k\}).$ Since $G$ is open, it is uncountable and at least one $n^{-1}(\{k\})$ is uncountable, so posseses an accumulation point $z_0 (\in G?)$. Therefore by the identity theorem $f^{(k)}$ is zero on $G$ and $f$ is a polynomial. My question is why $z_0\in G$?

Thanks a lot in advance for the help!

Comment: This is a well-known problem; see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial). (One small change is that any analytic function that's a polynomial on a disk is a polynomial everywhere.)

Comment: Re your edit: Note that http://math.stackexchange.com/a/995129/42969 defines the function $n$ on the *compact interval* $[0, 1]$. In your case, an arbitrary line segment in $G$ should work. As a compact set, it contains all accumulation points.

Comment: @Martin R  Thanks for the comment. Why is there an issue to work on the whole $G$ - or do you mean that a line segment is enough (in order for the compactness argument to work)?

Comment: A line segment is sufficient. – As I understand it (I am not an expert in topology) you can also apply the Baire Category Theorem (as in this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/995120/42969), either to a compact subset of $G$, or because BCT is valid in a locally compact Hausdorff space.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: An uncountable subset of a domain has an accumulation point in that domain, by the same argument that is used to show the existence of such a point in $\mathbb{C}$.