# Derivative of a given order vanishing on a connected open set implies function being a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following simple question: Suppose $f$ holomorphic from a connected open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ and that $f^{(N)} = 0$ on $U$ for some $N\in \mathbb{N}$. Show $f$ is a polynomial.

I understand that this could be done by an application of Taylor's theorem: For any $z\in U$, let $z\in B_r(a)$ for some $a\in U, r>0$. Then by Taylor's theorem, 
\begin{equation}
f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (z - a)^n = \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (z - a)^n,
\end{equation}
which is a polynomial. But this representation of $f$ depends on $z$ since different $z$ may result in different $a$ although $N$ is not affected. I wonder how to conclude that $f$ is a polynomial on $U$ from here. Thanks a lot.

**NOTE:** This question is not a duplicate of [Entire function with vanishing derivatives?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995105/entire-function-with-vanishing-derivatives). The answers in that question concluded directly $f$ is a polynomial from $f^{(N)} = 0$ on $U$ by Taylor's theorem. My question is exactly why this is true. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious here.

Please see José Carlos Santos' comments below for an answer. Many thanks to José!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entire function with vanishing derivatives?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995105/entire-function-with-vanishing-derivatives)

Comment: Hi @JoséCarlosSantos, I've edited my question to clarify the difference. Thanks!

Comment: You can easily prove by induction that if $f^{(N)}$ is the null function, then $f$ is a polynomial function whose degree is smaller than $N$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Right! Thanks! But could you please tell me if Taylor's theorem can be applied to get the same result when $U$ is not an open disc? I tried in my question above but I couldn't.

Comment: No, it doesn't follow directly from Taylor's theorem alone. But you can use it together with the identity theorem.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I see. That answered my question! Thanks a lot!