# For an entire function f such that for each complex number $c$ there is a positive integer $n$ with $f ^{(n)} (c) = 0$. Show that f is a polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is an entire function such that for each complex number $c$ there is a
positive integer $n$ with $f^{(n)}
(c) = 0$. Show that f is a polynomial.

I tried using Taylor series expansion with respect to the point $c$ but that didn't help.

Any hint will also work for me.

Comment: This has been asked here not long ago so try a search, but the idea is to use Baire theorem as the sets $F_n$ for which the above holds for precisely $n$ are closed and their union covers the plane, so one must have non empty interior and then identity theorem does the rest

Comment: @Conrad: There is an even simpler (IMO) [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/995129/42969) which does not need Baire's theorem.